# Why am I unable to generate more than 1 random string?

Tags: c, random

My code here will always generate one string of length `MAXLEN` but then start generating strings with a lower length. I'm not certain of why this is happening.

```
void generate_strings(int n) {
    char genvals[] = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABC"
                     "DEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789 ";
    char str[MAXLEN + 1];
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < MAXLEN; j++) {
            str[j] = genvals[rand() % strlen(genvals) - 1];
        }
        str[MAXSTRLEN] = '\0';
        printf("%s\n", str);
        memset(str, 0, MAXLEN);
    }

}
```

Comment: The expression `rand() % strlen(genvals) - 1` may well take the value `-1`, in which case your code has undefined behaviour.

Comment: @KerrekSB Removing the `-1` fixed it. For some odd reason I thought I'd never get the first value in `genvals` if I didn't put a -1 in there. Cheers.

Comment: Note: `char str[MAXLEN + 1];` and `str[MAXSTRLEN]`. Are they the same???

Comment: @PaulOgilvie I just tried `str[MAXSTRLEN]` and that crashed it. The function wouldn't be able to insert the nullbyte that way right?

Comment: It is not really clear what you want to accomplish. There is just too much missing. See [ask] and provide a [mcve].

Comment: I just miss the information that `MAXLEN == MAXSTRLEN` because you allocate an array `char str[MAXLEN + 1];` but terminate it at `MAXSTRLEN`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of changes:

1) As dazedandconfused pointed out in his answer, you need to seed the random number generator.

2) Don't calculate the length of `genvals` more than once.

3) Your indexing into `genvals` was incorrect.

4) The call to `memset` was unnecessary.

```
void generate_strings(int n) {
    srand(time(NULL)); // seed the random number generator
    char genvals[] = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABC"
                     "DEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789 ";
    size_t length = strlen(genvals); // only calculate this once
    char str[MAXLEN + 1];
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < MAXLEN; j++) {
            str[j] = genvals[rand() % length];
        }
        str[MAXLEN] = '\0';
        printf("%s\n", str);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Been a while since I worked with C but I think it is because you didn't seed it.  Try adding this above the for loop...

```
int seed = time(NULL);
srand(seed);
```